# Bot keeps crashing when wrong command is sent. [Discord JS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make an Arby's Bot. Whenever someone sends a message in the channel, the bot crashes and bot doesn't work.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("arbys") || message.guild.channel == message.guild.channels.cache.get("843008525335920651")) {
  } else
    setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 1);
  message.author.send("**arbys** Only Arbys. GOT IT?")
});
```

If someone could please help me that would be amazing.

Comment: Just check if `message.channel.id ==="843008525335920651"`, to check if the message is sent in the correct channel. Although, the question seems to be a bit unclear. Please attach the error if any.

Comment: What does `message.guild.channel == message.guild.channels.cache.get("843008525335920651")` represent? Think about it and when you enter the `else` (and when not).

Comment: There is probably some error message on the crash?

Comment: `message.author.send("**arbys** Only Arbys. GOT IT?")` is causing the error if i am not wrong. You need a `channel` object to send a message but `author` is an user object.

Comment: @binoy638, no, that's how you send direct messages. OP, please attach the error.

Answer (score 0):

[`message.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) doesn't have a `channel` property, but that's not the only problem. You can't compare an object (`message.guild.channel`) to another object (`message.guild.channels.cache.get("843008525335920651")`) like that. You can, however, check if the channel the message is sent in has the same ID as you want (`843008525335920651`).

You can also delete the message after you sent a DM to the message author using the `.then()` method. Check out the code below:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (
    message.content.startsWith('arbys') ||
    message.channel.id === '843008525335920651'
  ) {
    // do something ?
    console.log('Correct channel or command');
  } else {
    // send a DM to the author
    message.author
      .send('**arbys** Only Arbys. GOT IT?')
      // and delete the original message
      .then(() => message.delete())
      // catch them errors :)
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its because `message.guild` does not have a channel property, instead do this

`if (message.content.startsWith("arbys") || message.channel.id == "843008525335920651"){`

hope this helped >:D